# I don't know why my program is not entering the loop

Tags: c++, loops

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

   int ranking = 0;
   int population = 0;
   float leadingNumPercent = 0;
   float oneCounter = 0;
   float twoCounter = 0;
   float threeCounter = 0;
   float fourCounter = 0;
   float fiveCounter = 0;
   float sixCounter = 0;
   float sevenCounter =0;
   float eightCounter =0;
   float nineCounter =0;
   float overAllCounter =0;
   int i =0;
   string countryName;
   ifstream inFile;

   inFile.open("test.txt");

   while(!inFile.eof()){
      inFile >> ranking;
      inFile >> population;
      getline(inFile, countryName);

   while (population >= 10) {
      population = (population/10);

   }

   if (population < 10){
      if (population == 1){
         oneCounter++; 

         return oneCounter;

      }      
      if (population == 2){
         twoCounter++;
         return twoCounter;
      }   
      if (population==3){
         threeCounter ++;
         return threeCounter;
      }      
      if (population==4){
         fourCounter ++;
         return fourCounter;
      }      
      if (population==5){
         fiveCounter ++;
         return fiveCounter;

      }      
      if (population==6){
         sixCounter ++;
         return sixCounter;
      }    
      if (population==7){
         sevenCounter ++;
         return sevenCounter;
      }       
      if (population==8){
         eightCounter ++;
         return eightCounter;
      }    
      if (population==9){

         nineCounter ++;
         return nineCounter;
      }




   }
   leadingNumPercent = (oneCounter / 238)*100;
   cout << leadingNumPercent;

}
   inFile.close();





  return 0;


}
```

here is test.txt file that I link to http://www.buildingthepride.com/faculty/jajerkins/cs155-01/population2014.txt . it seems that the program wont enter the if(population  < 10){ if (population == 1) loop. I checked it using cout and the population is being reduced to a single digit

Comment: `I checked it using cout` You have `return oneCounter; cout << oneCounter;` The statement after `return` will never run, of course.

Comment: because population has value 0

Comment: I changed around the return in oneCounter and it is going into the loop but  when I leave the if loop and try to make it into a percentage  it comes up blank when I cout

Comment: population gets it value from infile

Comment: Same thing - you are returning from the function on the very first iteration of the loop, and before you get to `leadingNumPercent` calculation. I suggest you re-read the section of your favorite C++ textbook that describes the `return` statement.

Comment: alright :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `return` is the reason.

Also let me help you on your code.

1.- Does it really make sense to check if `population` is smaller than 10? If you want to avoid illogical errors better compare against negative values and warn the user if he indicated that in the text file. With the `while (population >= 10)` you are forcing the value become < than 10.

2.- Why to do all that complex comparison? How about:

```
int counter[10];
counter[population-1]++;
```

after

```
while (population >= 10) {
  population = (population/10);
}
```

instead of using all these ifs and comparing `population` again and again.

3.- Why are you using `return` anyways? You are breaking the whole program. Also `inFile.close()` is not going to happen that way. How about:

```
for(int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
{
    cout << "Number " << i << ": " << counter[i] << std::endl;
}
```

after the line

```
inFile.close();
```

4.- If you want to test some values why not `break` the `while(!inFile.eof())` loop and let `cout` show you the variables.

5.- Don't use `float` if you really mean integers. As you are counting quantities, use `int` or better yet `unsigned int`.

Comment: im still begining to learn c++ and I dont really what 

int counter[10];
counter[population-1]++;

does. I took off the returns and its working a bit better.

Comment: Good to know, I'm pretty sure you will become better if you practice.

Comment: I actually got it working ( as much as I need for the assignment) and am going to work on getting a for loop  and work on the tons of if's. Thank you for your help

Comment: and im converting the counter into a percentage so that is why I chose float.(percentage of leading number in population)